# Not able to convert Scala object to JSON String

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I am using Play Framework and I am trying to convert a Scala object to a JSON string.

Here is my code where I get my object:

```
val profile: Future[List[Profile]] = profiledao.getprofile(profileId);
```

The object is now in the `profile` value.

Now I want to convert that `profile` object which is a `Future[List[Profile]]` to JSON data and then convert that data into a JSON string then write into a file.

Here is the code that I wrote so far:

```
val jsondata = Json.toJson(profile)
Jackson.toJsonString(jsondata)
```

This is how I am trying to convert into JSON data but it is giving me the following output:

```
{"empty":false,"traversableAgain":true}
```

I am using the `Jackson` library to do the conversion.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: What type of `object` is your `profile` value ?

Comment: @meucaa That function profiledao.getprofile(profileid) returns Future[List[Profile]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother with Jackson? If you're using Play, you have `play-json` available to you, which uses Jackson under the hood FWIW:

First, you need an implicit `Reads` to let `play-json` know how to serialize `Profile`. If `Profile` is a case class, you can do this:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val profileFormat = Json.format[Profile]
```

If not, define your own `Reads` like [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators).

Then since `getprofile` (which should follow convention and be `getProfile`) returns `Future[List[Profile]]`, you can do this to get a `JsValue`:

```
val profilesJson = profiledao.getprofile(profileId).map(toJson)
```

(`profiledao` should also be `profileDao`.)

In the end, you can wrap this in a `Result` like `Ok` and return that from your controller.

Comment: I have an implicit reads that is returning back the JSON data right ? but how how to convert into the JSON String

Comment: The `Reads` doesn't produce JSON. It is a function that converts a Scala object to a `JsValue`. Once that function is applied, you can use `Json.stringify` to convert the `JsValue` to a String.

Comment: I think so the importing libraries matters a lot, because why i changed the import for the Json then it started working fine.thanks for all.

Comment: If you think my answer is incomplete or unclear, feel free to edit it. If it helped you solve your problem, please upvote and accept it so people with the same problem can find the answer quickly in the future.